# Multiple substrings with table and column aliases

Tags: mysql, subquery, substring, alias

Hello I am trying to write a query that will accomplish the following: (I am not that experienced with MySQL)

Extract the file extension of the page requested, just the file extension, from the origcmd field.  And it mush work regardless of the length of the file Extension.  I want to group it by the page and count how many records are in each group.  Then Order the grouped records in descending order by the field that counts the records in each grouping.

> Table: WebLog Columns: ipno, dunno1, dunno2 origdate, origzone,
>   origcmd, recode, bytes
>
> Data: 1.1.1.1, -, -, {15/Mar/2008:16:36:09, -0700}, GET
>   /images/noodle.jpg HTTP/1.1,200,335

Data output should look something like this:

```
| PageRequested | NumberOfHits |

+---------------+--------------+

| htm | 287 |

| gif | 217 |

| jpg | 48 |

| | 4 |

| xbm | 3 |

| cgi | 2 |

| txt | 2 |

| NULL | 2 |

| html | 1 |
```

I have this query that I am working on but I am having issues just with the first part I cannot find out what Aliases I need for the tables.

```
SELECT Substring_INDEX(PageRequested, '.', 1)
From(Select Substring_INDEX(origcmd, '.', -2)As PageRequested From WebLog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select PageRequested, 
   count(PageRequested) as Hits
from (
    select substring_index(substring_index(origcmd, '.', -2), ' ', 1) as PageRequested 
    from weblog) temp
group by PageRequested
order by Hits desc
```

Working SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94d04/3

Comment: Thanks for your response but I receive a PageRequested is an unknown column any suggestions?

Comment: @ Ashwin Mukhija Sorry I did not refresh the page after your edit I will try this one.

Comment: After running the second query it is pulling data but it is not pulling just the file extensions such as HTML, or JPG so on.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh wait, is HTTP1.1 also a part of origcmd?

Comment: Yeah it is.  I changed the number to -2 and it pulls the file extension but everything to the right of it as well.  I would like just the file extension

Comment: Oh well, I fixed that in my answer

Comment: your answer up there is really good and way better than what I had.  All I needed to do was change the -1 to a -2 and it worked.  It is now pulling just the extensions.  Thanks again for your help.  Regards